# Is there a way to use Dependency Injection to create a child object of a Factory with another parameter included?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out how/if Dependency Injection could be used in the following example:

Say I have a Factory class:

```
    public class IoTServiceFactory
    {
         public IoTServiceFactory()
         {
         }

         public async IIoTService CreateService(Parameters parameters)
         {
              DeviceClient deviceClient = await SetupDeviceClientAsync(parameters, cancellationToken);

              return new IoTService(deviceClient);
         }
    }
```

Now my Service class I want a constructor that not only takes in a DeviceClient but also an ILogger such as:

```
public class IoTService : IIoTService
{
    public IoTService (DeviceClient deviceClient, ILogger<IIoTService> logger)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to pass in ILogger into IoTServiceFactory constructor??

Comment: In your question, it appears `IoTCentralServiceFactory`, `IoTService`, `IIoTService`, `IoTServiceFactory`....

Comment: I believe there is no way, DI containers are mainly built around constuctor injection and you are building instance of your client manually. You could try implementing service locator antipattern, but I would not recommend this. Could you elaborate on the reason why you don't want to use factory constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of injection `ILogger` into IoTServiceFactory, you could inject `ILoggerFactory` so that you can [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-DE/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerfactoryextensions.createlogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-logging-loggerfactoryextensions-createlogger-1(microsoft-extensions-logging-iloggerfactory)) a logger for the service upon instantiation:

```
public class IoTServiceFactory
{
     private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

     public IoTServiceFactory(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     {
       _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
     }

     public async IIoTService CreateService(Parameters parameters)
     {
          DeviceClient deviceClient = await SetupDeviceClientAsync(parameters, cancellationToken);
          var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<IoTService>();
          return new IoTService(deviceClient, logger);
     }
}
```